# How/where is port-forwarding needed to establish a server-client connection

Tags: port, router

I am attempting to establish a connection between two computers using MSDN codes:

Client code:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737591(v=vs.85).aspx

Server code:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737593(v=vs.85).aspx

These codes run perfectly on a local network, but my intention is to establish a connection over the internet, where both computers are behind routers. I know port-forwarding is a viable solution. But I just don't know how.

For example, does even the client need port-forwarding, not just the server?

Further more, I am unable to properly configure my router to port-forward. Its model is Level One WBR-3407a. I tried this guide:
http://portforward.com/english/routers/port_forwarding/LevelOne/WBR-3407a/defaultguide.htm
But it didn't work. As you may note, this guide doesn't anywhere in it specify what port to use? is it possible to port-forward without specifying which port to forward?!

Comment: Why downvote? Is it a duplicate? I've had hardship looking everywhere for a whole day for a solution ending up finding nothing.

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure port forwarding on the router to which the "server" is connected, and yes, you do need to specify a port (there's an exception, but let's not worry about it now). You typically wouldn't need port forwarding on the router to which the client computer connects.

Looking at the MSDN code you linked, you need to port forward port 27015, so on the router for your server, you want to add port forwarding entries for incoming TCP connections on port 27015 and to forward them to the IP address of the computer running the server, also on port 27015.

For future reference, this question is more appropriate for [SuperUser](http://superuser.com) or, less likely, for [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com).

Comment: So the link on portforward.com provides incomplete steps for port-forwarding? I don't know how to add 27015 to my router configuration.

Comment: The instructions you link to seem to only allow forwarding for a number of well-known predefined services. I do not know (nor can I find out) if your router supports more extensive port forward. Again, your question is better suited for [superuser.com](http://superuser.com). You will be able to get help faster on by asking "*how do I do port forwarding on my WBR-3407a?*" on SuperUser.